# How to add new functionality to a class typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a main project, let's call it `main`. There is a library, let's call it `A`, which contains some classes. Let library `A` contain the class Cat.

```
class Cat {
    name: string
}
```

There is another library, let's call it `B`, which contains some functions. For example `meow`.

```
function meow(delay: number) {
    //some code
}
```

The challenge is as follows. The library should `A` be independent and work in any project (I will import it into my `main` project). Library `B` is not needed in all projects, so it can be imported to some project, and to some it cannot be imported. Libraries `B`'s job is to extend library `A` and embed, for example, a `meow` function in the cat class.

That is, if only library `A` is connected in my `main` project, then the `Cat` class will contain only 1 property `name`, if library `B` is imported along with library `A`, then the `Cat` class will be expanded and will contain the `name` property and the `meow` function.

How to achieve this result?

Comment: This can likely be accomplished through [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#introduction), but I'm having a hard time getting a reproducible project that behaves the way you want.  Do you have a [mcve] as a link to a project in a cloud IDE that I could modify?  (I don't want to install anything locally.)

Comment: @jcalz https://codesandbox.io/s/main-project-tmiq5   . ```A``` library and ```B``` library are modules that will need to be imported as npm packages. Library ```A``` contains the main classes and it will always be imported and work on its own. Sometimes it requires extending the functionality of the classes of library ```A```, so library ```B``` is added, but it only has to modify the existing classes in library ```A```.

Comment: Great, thanks.  Try [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/main-project-forked-y45rm?file=/src/Zoo.ts).  If this works well enough for you I'll write up an answer, but there are plenty of caveats to this sort of declaration merging, it seems.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look now

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, this really works for me. You can leave your answer and I will vote for it. And one more small question. library ```B``` does not see the type ```Cat```, because library ```A``` and library ```B``` are 2 different modules. Is it possible somehow to add all types of library ```A``` to library ```B```, without their implementation?

Comment: I don't get it... if `B` doesn't have access to `A`, and `A` doesn't have access to `B`, where would you want to add `B`'s functionality to `A`?  In `Zoo`?  Would that work for you?

Comment: Like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/main-project-forked-xebhx?file=/src/Zoo.ts). But there's no magical way for `B.meow` to get added to instances of `A.Cat`.  You either need to do it yourself when you import the libraries, or `B` needs to do it, or `A` needs to do it.

Comment: @jcalz The first version you threw off was great. It's just that when developing module ```B```, I would like the IDE to tell me what is in the ```Cat``` class, while not including the library A itself. Maybe you can write a separate declaration file for the entire library ```A``` to include only this declaration in ```B```, without the implementation itself. Is it possible?

Comment: @jcalz In your first solution, in [CatsFunk.ts](https://codesandbox.io/s/main-project-forked-y45rm?file=/src/packages/library-b/CatsFunc.ts) on line 10, the name is known for the IDE and it prompts that the ```Cat``` has a ```name``` field, this works because we have connected the entire library A. Is it possible to describe all types of library ```A``` and connect to library ```B```, only types ```A```?

Comment: You can certainly write a separate declaration file but you need the implementation of `B` to actually modify `Cat.prototype` at runtime, so I don't quite see how to avoid having `B` import `A`. I'm not an expert on modules so I'm not sure how or if that could actually work out. And I wouldn't dare to guess without first testing on a [mcve] of the exact setup required here: that would look like multiple projects or repos, right?  Not sure I'd even know where to start.  Anyway I'm happy to write up my original answer if that is still useful without the added piece of `B` not depending on `A`.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you very much for your answer. Yes, you understood correctly. there is a main project for github. There are 2 libraries, which are also stored as separate repositories on the github. And the repository ```A``` submodule is connected to the main project. And then, if additional functionality is needed, library ```B``` is also connected as a submodule.